# Charge a connected account using stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to take money out of a connect account using stripe. So say the connected account has a balance of $50, I want to take out $5. The purpose of this is to "charge" the connected account a fee for making an instant payout. So right before the instant payout call is made, I want to take out money from the connected accounts balance.

I was thinking to do a [direct charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges), but first off, there will be a 1% stripe fee, and that will charge the debit card/bank account. I just want to adjust the balance before the payout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for transfers, which is how you move money between Stripe accounts without having to pay the Stripe fee: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits#transferring-from-a-connected-account

Heads up though, this is only available if your platform and connected accounts are both located in the same region, which has to be US, Europe or Japan.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Do you know if there's a stripe fee when using the transfer or charge method?

Comment: The fee only applies when you're moving money around using the card networks (e.g. Visa and Mastercard). Internal transfers between Stripe accounts won't be charged a fee.